# TV episode or movie involving space dinosaurs and teleportation

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv, teleportation, dinosaurs

I remember watching something on TV where when humans became space-faring, they meet dinosaurs that have advanced technology.

They give the humans the technology to teleport vast distances, like in *Star Trek*. But when you teleport, a new body is created at the destination, then upon confirmation that you reached the destination, the original body is destroyed; it is called "balancing the equation."

A technician starts the procedure to teleport this woman, but the link is lost, so he doesn't know if she reached the destination. He falls in love with her while waiting for the connection to be restored and for confirmation of her arrival. Once the teleportation is confirmed, he doesn't want to destroy the woman.

This seems like a *The Outer Limits* or *The Twilight Zone* format. I'm pretty sure it isn't *The Twilight Zone* though.

Comment: Not what you're looking for, but for a related concept, see Doctor Who "Ice Warriors" episodes.  Contains all of "humans becoming space faring", "reptillian humanoids with advanced technology" and teleportation.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I believe this is the *The Outer Limits* episode, "[Think Like a Dinosaur](https://theouterlimits.fandom.com/wiki/Think_like_a_Dinosaur)".

> Michael Burr is the only permanent human occupant of the Tuulen station, situated on a vast empty plain of the Moon. **His companions are the Hanen, an emotionless, dinosaur-like alien species who have developed a highly-advanced means of long-distance travel by 'jumping' through space. Achieved by creating an exact duplicate of the jumper, the copy is reconstituted at the destination point and the original destroyed, thus leaving only one.**
>
> Kamala Shastri is one of the test jumpers to arrive for travel to the planet Gend, but in the final stage of the transfer, something inexplicable happens. Confirmation of her duplicate's arrival is not received from Gend and the procedure is temporarily aborted. **When it's later determined that Kamala's copy does indeed exist, Michael is called upon to 'balance the equation' and eliminate the original.** Michael knows the human race is desperate to access a technology that would allow them to leave behind a planet now virtually destroyed by pollution and over-population. He also knows it is imperative that he avoid a protocol breach with the Hanen, but can he bring himself to kill Kamala?
>
> Michael slowly develops feelings for Kamala, and he remembers his deceased wife whom he could not save from disease. Because of this, he can't bring himself to kill Kamala. Michael is eventually convinced by the Hanen that "duplicates" create too many problems, and he deceives Kamala into thinking he will help her escape only to release her from an airlock. Two years later, the "real" Kamala returns (she's actually a copy of the copy since she jumped back) and recognizes Michael as her co-ordinator on that original jump. Obviously tormented from murdering her original, Michael claims that she must be mistaken.

The episode is based on the short story ["Think like a dinosaur" by James Patrick Kelly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Think_Like_a_Dinosaur), originally published in the June 1995 issue of Asimov's Science Fiction magazine

Comment: Wow, that was quick! Nice job!

Comment: I read that story just last night!